# Select query not retrieving records when executed in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am having a doubt, can anyone please explain me why I am getting record in select query but not able to get the same when the query is executed from a stored procedure

Below ,select query retrieving records
[image]

and here no records for the same query in stored procedure

[image]

Comment: increase size of your procedure datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out the name is more than varchar(25) and same may hold true for other values of mnthname as well. So alter funciton definition as:

```
Alter proc FindsSring
(
@name varchar(max),
@STD varchar(10),
@Div varchar(2),
@month varchar(100)
)
As ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `@name` parameter of type `varchar(25)` is to small to fit the example name in the query. It would be truncated and the query would give no result.